# How was Rebekah able to enter the Salvatore home?

Tags: the-vampire-diaries

The question addresses an event in the third season of the TV show *The Vampire Diaries*.

In the universe of *The Vampire Diaries*, a vampire cannot enter a house without being invited as long as it is owned/occupied by a living person. Towards the end of season two of *The Vampire Diaries*, Elena got the deed to the Salvatore home to provide her with a safe place. However, in season three episode six, *Smells Like Teen Spirit*, Rebekah, one of the original vampires, walked into the house without an invitation from Elena. How was Rebekah able to do this?

- Did I miss when Elena invited her in? I do not think this is true since from the dialogue in the scene, Rebekah indicated this was her first time inside the house.
- Are original vampires not limited in this way? This cannot be true because I remember in season two when Elena woke up Elijah, another original vampire, he had to go outside the house very quickly because he was not invited in.
- Does Elena not own the house anymore?
- Is this an error on the show writer's part?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Salvatore house is no longer owned by Elena because if you remember, Elena died in Season 2 and thus now no longer owns the house.

- Rebekah was not invited in by anyone.
- Even original vampires still need an invite. Remember that no vampire could enter the secret cave in season 3.
- No, Elena no longer owns the house because she died during the sacrifice.
- Nope, not a writer error.

The episode when Elena died is the end of Season 2

> when she was sacrificed (murdered) by Klaus, who needed to perform the ritual of her death and one vampire and one werewolf, so as to break the curse keeping him from becoming a hybrid. However, remember that her father did a spell to sacrifice his own life so that Elena would be brought back to life, which is the reason Elena didn't die permanently, since she is not immortal and does not have one of the immortal rings.

Comment: Can you please remind me the event when Elena died? How is she alive today as a non-vampire? I think, special ring would not work on Elena as she isn't normal human..

Comment: @SachinShekhar see http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sun_Also_Rises#Plot

Comment: Oh, just remembered that episode.. I've forgotten about that f**king magic...

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen I think, you should check-mark this answer..

Comment: she may have died but she's still alive and therefore should still have the dead to the house unless she gave it back. it shouldn't have mattered that she was sacrificed or not

Comment: Was there some explanation of this on the show itself or is this just a guess? It doesn't make sense that the house is unowned because she died and came back? As far as the local government goes, Elena didn't die, unless local governments suddenly accept supernatural resurrection...

Comment: Elena DID die, and even though she was brought back to life, she is no longer naturally alive, she was brought to live by supernatural forces. When she died, it broke the ownership of the house. This is not a "guess", this is a fact.

Comment: It was a flaw. If Elena died during the sacrifice, she would've been a vampire. She would've died with Damon's blood in her system. She wasn't Resuscitated

Answer (score 2):

Damon said that because Elena died she longer owns the house. Even though she died temporary, she still died whatever magic that keeps vampires out of the house was broken. Vampires were created by magic, which means vampires are blocked from homes by magic.

Answer (score 1):

Damon said it to Abby once, you don't need to be invited into the Salvatore house because, although Elena legally is the owner of the house, she was in fact dead for a period of time. Her death means that the "magical" contract is broken, so even when there's a document that says that Elena owns the house the rule does not apply anymore to any vampire.

That's why Bex was able to enter the house without invitation. All vampires can enter freely into that house.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that it still seems like a flaw in the show. After all, Alaric has "died" several times during the show, only being resurrected due to his magic ring. However, vampires still don't have permission to enter his apartment without his say-so. If "magic resurrections" don't count, then his ring shouldn't count either. Therefore his residence shouldn't be protected.

Comment: we don't know how Alaric's ring works vs. the spell Elena's father used, there is clearly a difference in terms of "actually being dead", I suppose. Since Klaus needed to kill a doppleganger to unlock his wolf side, which he did, Elena must really have died.

Answer (score 0):

Elena was revived by magic with the lifeforce of her father, the ring prevents Alaric from dying from supernatural entities not dying in general...  Due to Elena being a doppelganger the ring wouldn't work for her because it does not work for supernaturals, they were contemplating four ways to revive her; the ring, Elijahs potion, vampire blood and then Jons way

Would turning her of even worked anyway? Klaus drains all if her blood, which I imagine would of included Damons